# StreamReader Lectura Audio

Tags: c#, codificación, audio, stream

Estoy realizando una consulta a un sitio web el cual me devuelve una respuesta

El problema es que la respuesta es un archivo con extensión .acc y el StreamReader que lee la respuesta esta cambiando los caracteres originales (adjunto 2 imágenes para referencia al final)

Esto se comprueba al descargar el archivo a través del navegador donde una vez descargado funciona perfectamente

Existe algún otro reader o manera de leerlo para que el archivo quede como el original?

El codigo que utilizo para obtener la respuesta es el siguiente:

```
        public static string RealizarPedido(string url)
    {
        string html = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        return html;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: StreamReader lee texto.  Si queire bytes, tal vez un NetworkStream sea más a proposito.

Comment: cual es la url, te puedo ayudar

Comment: La url cambia constantemente ya que es un stream. Un ejemplo es capturar el archivo de audio que envia alguna radio ejemplo: http://www.fmrockandpop.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comentarte que al convertir los bytes a caracteres en tu línea:

```
html = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Puede que no sea la misma codificación (`UTF8`, `UTF32`) que manejas en tu aplicación por ejemplo y eso conlleva a que use otro símbolo (caracter) si no es encontrado en ese contexto de la codificación, lo recomendable es que lo guardes directamente usando un stream de Memoria `MemoryStream` y de ahí a un archivo si esa es tu intención.

```
        public void RealizarPedido(string url)
        {
            string html = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);                

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    Byte[] info = GetBytes(stream);    

                    using(FileStream file = new FileStream("demo.aac", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)){
                       file.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
       }

       public byte[] GetBytes(Stream source)
       {
           if (source == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
           if (source is MemoryStream)
               return (source as MemoryStream).ToArray();
           using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               source.CopyTo((Stream)memoryStream);
               return memoryStream.ToArray();
           }
       }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Estas utilizando la libreria de System.IO ? stream.GetBytes() no es una funcion de esa libreria para ese objeto. Por otro lado, cuando se define el MemoryStream no esta siendo utilizado para guardar el archivo con el FileStream, ademas el FileStream no tiene el using

Comment: Lo hice como ejercicio mental, sin usar visual studio. Ya lo corrijo.

Comment: El using es para no tener que definir explícito el cierre del stream, como tenía una llamada al método close es lo mismo.

Comment: Excelente, funciono a la perfección muchas gracias !